# Uploading apk to Nexus, maven plugins are the only way?

Tags: android, gradle, apk, nexus

I was trying to upload my release apk file to the Nexus repository and all I could find was maven related plugins and a curl command. I couldn't find a way to just upload an apk to nexus repository from gradle. Here is the code which is working currently

```
uploadResultArchives {
repositories {
    repository(url: "http://localhost:8081/repository/myrepo/") {
        authentication(userName: "admin", password: "admin123")
    }
    pom.version = "66"
    pom.artifactId = "my-awesome-app"
    pom.groupId = "com.my.awesom-app"
    pom.packaging = "apk"
 }
}

artifacts{
  resultArchives file: file('build/outputs/apk/release/my-app-release.apk')
}
```

this code works and uploads the apk to nexus. but the problem is it creates a whole lot of other things with the apk ( folders are getting created on the basis of groupId, there are pom files, sha files, metadata files).

All I needed was an apk to upload. and I can manage the name dynamically in gradle anyway so no duplicates will get published.

please advise me about how to upload a single apk or ignoring all the other files created because of the maven plugin I use. In the documentation, I saw an ***Upload*** task but no Idea how to use that to upload a file

Answer (score 1):

Nexus is a Maven Repository Manager and Maven repositories require all of those files:

- pom.xml: Describes your project
- sha and md5 files: Checksums to verify the integrity of the artifact files

You will most probably not be able to get rid of those wiles and subfolders as they are part of the maven repository specification.

If all you need is the file to be uploaded somewhere, an FTP server might be more useful.

Comment: but, in the case of an android app. I might not need all these things plus I have seen an option to create a raw repository in nexus  and I am able to upload single files using curl command